# Pdf.js : How to load file + view -- An error occurred while loading the PDF. More InformationClose (Searching for "normal" example)

Tags: javascript, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

I copy-paste the source from this example:
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

My Code example (No docs so I follow the source code):
https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/bGdMPqe
[image]

I don't find **any** call to PDF `url` under the official example (Filename is: `compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf`) + The docs missing + Zero examples out there (Codepen/Jfiddle).

I am searching for the **most basic hello-world example** (**Very weird "unusable" docs for `pdf.js`** ==> "can't see the forest for the trees").

The official examples here not helpful (Where is the UI bar?): https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

Answer (score 0):

@Ezra

If your purpose of using it as a viewer plugin in your website/app. Please add the plugin to your website or web application and redirect the call to this snippet.

```
<a href="/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fyourpdf.pdf">Open yourpdf.pdf with PDF.js</a>
```

Additionally, you can refer for more information - https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-pdf.js-in-a-website

Comment: Thanks. Yes (I want to add this pdf-viewer to webflow). 
Your link is again an example of "bad docs" without any working example (Snippet).
Add this CDN --> Add this HTML --> Instalize --> DONE (Examples by GULP or webpack not helping me).

Comment: Check my answers or github, made an adjusted PDF.js with sort, reorder 
 and merge of text fragments for better screen reader experience or export, starting in Node.js + puppeteer and I am able to read PDF and export text layer w/o user interaction, there is a build branch - 2(?) webpack JSs and that is all, but default PDF used does not work (CORS) - working on local.